# TFS build agent, same port as team server?

Tags: tfs, build

My team foundation is setup to use port 8080, when I am creating a new build agent it defaults to port 9191.

Which one should I use?

I am getting an error when I try and run my build, it says the build agent was unreachable.

I created a share on my drive c:\tfsbuilds, and I added the TFSService account and gave it full rights.

I am using the \computername\tfsbuilds as my path to the builds folder.

What else could be wrong?

**Error message**

Team Foundation Build on computer TFSBUILDS.MyServer1.local (port 9191) is not responding. (Detail Message: Unable to connect to the remote server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has the Build service been started?  This is probably the most common issue as the service will need to be started first.  And yes, 9191 is the default port for the build agents.  Can you also check your firewall?

Comment: Is the only way to start the service using the command line?  I queued the build using the GUI, should that automatically start the service?

Comment: Hi Blankman.  Go to your TFS server, open services (Click windows key, type services.msc) and check that the build service is started.

Comment: Ok the vs service is not there, it must be on another server.  Let me investigate thanks!

Comment: The service is not even on our main TFS box.  Is it a seperate addon to get that service?

Comment: Yes, you need to install Team Foundation Build. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181710(VS.80).aspx  I think its an extra install as part of TFS.